# trouble with ALL of the backbone association plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

There is something about the basic setup of my Rails with backbone app that is keeping ALL of the major backbone associations solutions from working.

Even with nearly identical simple models/collections to those shown in their (rather limited) docs, I am running into the same problem with several different potential solutions (Relational, JJRelational, backbone-association).

For some reason when it goes to set up the "relational stuff" from my backbone model definition, it is dying when it tries to do "this.__set(models, options)" (each of them has a slightly different syntax for this basic operation -- all of them show that the super class "set" method is undefined!)

There must be something about my app setup or selection of gems etc. that is causing this, but I've run out of ideas.

Here is some context:
Rails 4 "scaffold" generated app with backbone-rails added and jquery rails and jquery ui added.

Where does the "set" method come from and what could cause it to be missing?  With each of these different associations add-ons, I have found that the basic model definitions and how I'm using them work fine as long as I leave the "relations" block of the model commented out.  With that commented out, the association-related code doesn't need to override "set", so all proceeds normally.

Comment that back in and each of them finds the original "set" to be undefined and can't get past that.

I would include my code here, but since it is doing the same thing with several different association add-ons (each with the models defined exactly as shown in their example), it seems the problem is outside of my model def.'s.

I have googled my fingers to the bone with no resolution.  Any ideas are welcome (even crazy ones).

help?